# Filter media upload attachment meta

Tags: filters, media, title

I'm trying to determine a way to access the meta data for an image when it is **first uploaded** with the media uploader.

Looking at the media_handle_upload() function in /wp-admin/includes/media.php I can't see any filters before the meta data is sent to wp_insert_attachment() wp_update_attachment_metadata().

Sure, I can filter the meta inside using the 'wp_update_attachment_metadata' filter. But this fires inside the wp_update_attachment_metadata() function.

I need a filter the meta data (specifically the title) when a new image is uploaded, not every time meta data is updated.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use add_attachment action.

I had a similar problem and I recently found your plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/format-media-titles/

:-)

Comment: Yeah I figured it out and created a Plugin! :)